# Integrate Grammarly with Slack

Tags: slack

I used to have Grammarly and Slack integrated. Every time I wrote a message in Slack, I had Grammarly suggestions, but when I replaced my computer, I couldn’t make that work again. I am unsure which steps I followed to make it work, and I couldn’t find the solution on Google.

Comment: Do you have Grammarly installed? Does it work in other applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you had the [Grammarly desktop app](https://www.grammarly.com/desktop). Maybe you just need to re-install it, should work in most apps where you can type.

Comment: That's probably correct but then it doesn't seem to work for the OP.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you @combdn, that make the trick, I went into https://app.grammarly.com/apps and I have to reinstall `Grammarly for Mac`

Comment: @nohillside obviously the answer is clear enough for the OP.